# How to reduce GSI .img file size to flash in system partition?

Tags: twrp, fastboot, huawei, partitions, gsi

I want to install a GSI to Huawei P10, but it does not accept big files to flash in the system partition: `ProjectElixir_4.0_arm64_bgN-14.0-20240108-1305-OFFICIAL`.
When I try to flash it via fastboot, I get:
`FAILED (remote: 'sparse flash write failure')`

How to reduce the .img of the GSI?

Comment: How do you know the problem is the gsi size? The error just mentions a write error.

Comment: when i try to flash it from twrp i get an error saying that the size is big. (i don't remember the correct error message now).

Comment: The may be it would be a good idea to include the full output into your question.